# Supress the intersection of two dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, dataframe

I understand it is basic in python but I didn't find a proper way to do the following thing...

I have 2 dataframe made of dates. 
The first one contain 300 dates arround, the second contain 20 dates arround.

I want to create a new dataframe made of the 300 dates without the 20 contained in the second dataframe.

```
[in] Dates1 
[out]
1    2017-03-10
2    2017-03-09
3    2017-03-08
4    2017-03-07
5    2017-03-06 
6    2017-03-03
7    2017-03-02
8    2017-03-01
9    2017-02-28
10   2017-02-27
etc... 

[in] Dates2
[out]
 1    2017-03-03
 2    2017-03-01

expectedResult
[out]
1    2017-03-10
2    2017-03-09
3    2017-03-08
4    2017-03-07
5    2017-03-06 
6    2017-03-02
7    2017-02-28
8    2017-02-27
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `~isin`

```
Dates1.loc[~Dates1.iloc[:, 0].isin(Dates2.iloc[:, 0])]

            1
0            
1  2017-03-10
2  2017-03-09
3  2017-03-08
4  2017-03-07
5  2017-03-06
7  2017-03-02
9  2017-02-28
10 2017-02-27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first merge and go heavy

result = df1.append(df2)
 data = result.drop_duplicates()